# Python Selenium Chrome - How to refresh a page if it takes too long to load the page for the first time

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to refresh a page if the loading time exceeds my expectation. So I plan to use existing function set_page_load_timeout(time_to_wait), but it turns out that call driver.get() seems not to work anymore.

I've written a simple program below and hit the problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

import time



driver = webdriver.Chrome()
time.sleep(5)

driver.set_page_load_timeout(2)

try:
    driver.get("https://aws.amazon.com/")
except TimeoutException as e:
    print str(e)

driver.set_page_load_timeout(86400)

time.sleep(5)

print "open page"
driver.get("https://aws.amazon.com/")
print "page loaded"
```

**The environment info:** 
 
chrome=67.0.3396.99

chromedriver=2.40.565386 (45a059dc425e08165f9a10324bd1380cc13ca363),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.4 x86_64

Selenium Version: 3.12.0

or see:
[environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI66O.jpg)

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is an unfortunate situation when `get`/`navigation` timeouts the connection is not stable, so you can't operate well on the browser again.

The only workaround that exists as of now is to disable the `pageLoadStrategy`, but then you loose lot of good perks which automatically wait for pageLoad on `get` and `click` operations

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

import time

from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities

cap = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
cap["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=cap)
```